# What is the continuation of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly) Wikipedia link, at the very bottom of the article there is an equation $M = \nu - 2esin\nu + $ .... (see the link for the full equation)

What is the continuation of that series?

I'm using this equation for a program I'm writing but it doesn't seem to be precise enough, but I don't know what kind of series this is or the rules for continuing it.

Comment: Seems to be a fourier expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at Smart's Celestial Mechanics, the book this series is from, I'm not sure how to derive it, but if you have the eccentricity $e$ and the true anomaly $\nu$, you can use Kepler's equation

$$M = E - e\sin E$$

where $E$ is the eccentric anomaly in combination with

$$\cos \nu = \frac{\cos E - e}{1 - e \cos E} \implies \cos E = \frac{\cos \nu+e}{1 + e \cos \nu} \implies E = \arccos \left( \frac{\cos \nu+e}{1 + e \cos \nu} \right)$$

to get the mean eccentricity.